# Git - replace working tree files with those from a certain (last) commit

Tags: git

I have a git repository, currently on `master` branch. The last commit (`f3d8237` has about a dozen files (all `modified`). Most of these files are different from their fellows in the working directory.

**What I want to do is this: for each file in `f3d8237`, replace the corresponding file in the working tree with this file.**

I have been swimming through SO for this specific scenario. This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12049323/2554788 seems to capture my scenario most closely, but based on the myriad of other answers and comments on this thread, I'm intimidated to take a plunge. Don't want to make things worse!

Of course, it's probably clear I haven't even cut my `git` milk teeth yet.

Comment: `git checkout -- filename` for each of those files will work, but you're looking for a one liner I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only f3d8237 | while read line
do 
   git checkout f3d8237 -- $line
done
```

As for you being worried about the changes, if not satisfied you can always revert the changes by,

```
git reset --hard
```

Comment: Thanks for the sleek "pretty format" thing. I work on Windows PowerShell, but I'm sure I could also pipe into `foreach` and go on from there. However, I just went on to export those files using TortoiseGit, then merge  them over the working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @pratZ's approach, I ended up recreating, then solving the problem using Windows PowerShell. I thought I should go ahead and post my actual solution here (since it might be helpful to others) while accepting his answer.

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only f3d8237 | foreach{ git checkout f3d8237 -- $_ }
```

This retains the repository HEAD at `f3d8237` which was the last commit, but replaces all working copies with the corresponding file.